# Read 0 bytes after writing to /dev/ttyS0

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port, tty

I have been trying to perform serial communication on linux via the /dev/ttyS devices but when I try to read from them after writing I read no data.

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello world\n");
    int n;
    int fd;
    char c;
    int bytes;

    char buffer[10];
    char *bufptr;
    int nbytes;
    int tries;
    int x;
    struct termios options;

    fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if(fd == -1) {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open:");
    } else

    tcgetattr(fd, &options);

    // Set the baudrate, same speed for both I/O
    cfsetispeed(&options, B150);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B150);

    // Enable reading
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

    // Set 'RAW' mode
    cfmakeraw(&options);

    // Set byte size
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;

    // Set parity
    // options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag |= PARENB;
    options.c_cflag |= PARODD;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;

    // Set StopBits, @Linux no OneHalf is supproted, so OneHalf and Two are the same
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;

    // Set Handshake options
    // options.c_iflag |= CRTSCTS;
    // options.c_iflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    // options.c_cflag &= ~( IXON | IXOFF | IXANY );
    options.c_cflag |= IXON | IXOFF | IXANY;

    // Set Timeouts 
    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; // read() will return after receiving  character
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 10; // == 0 - infinite timeout, != 0 - sets timeout in deciseconds

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
    tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

    bytes = write(fd, "ATZ\r",4);
    printf(" wrote %d bytes\n", bytes);
    bufptr = buffer;

    bytes = read(fd, bufptr, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("number of bytes read is %d\n", bytes);
    perror ("read error:");

    for (x = 0; x < 10 ; x++) {
        c = buffer[x];
        printf("%d  ",c);
    }

    tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
    close(fd);
    printf("\n");
    return (0);
}
```

The program output is as follows

```
hello world
 wrote 4 bytes
number of bytes read is 0
read error:: Success
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Although I expected it to read the 4 characters I just wrote it seems that read reads 0 bytes. In case i put VTIME to 0 then read blocks forever. I have tried to do `echo /dev/ttyS0` but no output comes out. Any idea what might cause this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Do you have a physical loopback dongle plugged into `/dev/ttyS0`? If you don't, and assuming the seriall port is an RS232 port, it's easy to create one: https://www.sealevel.com/support/how-to-construct-serial-loopback-adapter-plugs/

Comment: If you expect to read what you wrote, the other end of the serial should copy ("echo") those chars back to you. More generally, you receive only what the other side sends to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code apparently is ok, except for the following facts:

- You call `perror("read error");` *after calling `printf(3)`, and not right after `read(2)`* so the possible error (if happened) is masked to the call to `read(2)` by the call to `printf(3)`. If you want to print the number of read characters, save the value of `errno` and the returned value from `read(2)` before calling `printf(3)`, and then, if the returned error is neg, then call `perror(3)`.
- Anyway.  The `c_cc[VTIME] = 10` imposes a *one second timeout*, and this is too sort for resetting a modem.  Your line settings are:

  ```
  CS8, Parity ODD, one STOP bit, and 150 baudrate
  ```

  Normally, modems answer to `ATZ\r` command *after resetting*, which takes some time (frequently more than a second) *and in the default modem speed* (because you have reset it) and *not at the speed at which you have send the `AT` command.*

  Resetting a modem is, for this reason, done blindly normally, and then you send a simple `AT\r` command, in order to ask for an `\r\nOK\r\n` response.  The answer to `AT\r` command is normally immediate, not as the response to a reset command, and lets the modem adjust its communication settings according to the received chars.

  Modems always adapt their speed when the `A` and `T` sequence is received, by sampling the square pulses received at a high sampling frequency, then they switch speed to the detected and normally do speed conversion (making it possible to talk to the modem at a different speed than the negotiated remotely)